# java.lang.IllegalStateException Unable to create new file: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1509245737788.jpg

Tags: android

its happened when i take a photo,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is in Manifest,is Android 4.2.1,its only happened in XiaoMi device. This is the takePhoto() complete code.

```
    public static Uri takePhoto(Context context, final String fileName, File path){
    Intent intent = null;
    Uri uri= null;
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();  
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        file = new File(path,fileName);
        if(file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            path.mkdirs();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Utils.showToast(context,"创建路径异常");
            Utils.isLogError("FilePath","创建路径异常："+Log.getStackTraceString(e),isLog);
        }
        if (currentapiVersion < 24) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,fileName);
            uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
        }else {
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
        }
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }else{
        Utils.showToast(context,"SD卡未挂载");
    }
    return uri;
}
```

this is the log :

```
Unable to create new file: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1509245804437.jpg
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:936)
com.sdj.wallet.util.Utils.takePhone(Utils.java:1727)
com.sdj.wallet.activity.AuthenticatioIdentityCardPicActivity.onClick(AuthenticatioIdentityCardPicActivity.java:402)
```

Comment: Add the full stacktrace

Comment: How do you got the `path`?

Comment: i use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to got the paht

Comment: Please provide your complete takePhone() method.

Comment: @Yuliwee sorry,is takePhote(),no takePhone()，my mistake，the code i was provided.

Comment: @KKaKa Did you find a root cause of this issue ? How did you fix it ?